# Angular Ajax request sending object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

i am editing content in an object saved in my AngularJs scope. Once submited i execute the following function:

```
$scope.saveQuestion = function(){       
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "/manager/evaluations/evaluations/manage_questions/537c6179-8ed8-49b4-ac6b-25715f550349", 
        data: {EvaluationQuestion: $scope.newquestion}
    });
}
```

$scope.newquestion has the following object:

```
[relevance: 3, evaluation_topic_id: 1, type: "text", action: "add", name: "asdfasdfsadfas"]
```

But the ajax request on the is just showing a Request Payload with:

Request Payloadview source

```
  {EvaluationQuestion:[]}
    EvaluationQuestion: []
```

**Can any one guess why the sent data is empty?**

Comment: Is the `$scopre` a typo?

Comment: Try `console.log($scope.newquestion)` just before the `$http()`. I suspect that the `$scope.newquestion` is still an empty array at the time a request is made.

Comment: The data showing the $scope.newquestion just before the $http() is posted in the question and continues to return the same array:

[relevance: 3, evaluation_topic_id: 1, type: "text", action: "add", name: "Test again with console.log() just above the http() request"…]

The feeling i got, is that calling the $scope.newquestion inside the $http call is not working....

Comment: Can you create a plunker or something so we can completely see everything? Also, try stepping through the code using chrome or firebug to really track what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your `$scope.newquestion` is an **Array**, not an Object.

JSON doesn't support an Array data type with named keys in it. For example:

```
var foo = [];
foo['bar'] = 'One';
foo.baz = 'Two';

JSON.stringify(foo); // return "[]"
```

If the `$scope.newquestion` isn't required to be an Array, just use an Object.

Instead of

```
$scope.newquestion = [];
```

change it to:

```
$scope.newquestion = {};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using a wrong JSON syntax in $scope.newquestion. 
Here you are defining an object which is supposed to be enclosed in {} but you are enclosing it in [] which stands for an array. I js arrays you cannot have `[name1: value1, name2: value2]`.

Try replacing the square brackets with curely brackets, something like this:

```
{relevance: 3, evaluation_topic_id: 1, type: "text", action: "add", name: "asdfasdfsadfas"}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> data: {EvaluationQuestion: angular.toJson($scope.newquestion)}

Comment: Did not work, the Request Payload is the following doing that:

EvaluationQuestion: "[]"

Comment: Console.log($scope.newquestion)::  [relevance: 3, evaluation_topic_id: 1, type: "text", action: "add", name: "asdfsad fsdaf sda"]  ------ Console.log(angular.toJson($scope.newquestion)):: []